# What is the closure of the set $B=\{(\frac{1}{n}, 0) \in\mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: general-topology

what is the closure of the following set

$B=\{(\frac{1}{n}, 0) \in\mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

I get the following;

$cl(B)=int(B)\ \cup \ \partial(B)= B \ \cup \{0,1\} = [1,0]$.

However in the solutions it states

$cl(B)=int(B)\ \cup \ \partial(B)= B \ \cup \{0\} = (1,0]$.

Where have i gone wrong?

Image of question and solution

[Question 2(ii)(b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Oyb.jpg)

[Answer 2(ii)(b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DprmO.jpg)

Comment: It is unclear how your $B$ is defined, for instance is it the union of all those intervals? Your notation just implies the collection of those intervals

Comment: It can't be the interval I suppose? there is no $x$ so that $1/n <x<0$.

Comment: First of all, is this the set of intervals of the form $(0,1/n)$ or the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(1/n,0)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You should make clear the topological space containing the points of $B$.  The notion of closure depends on which topology you impose on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Have you changed or added to the solution key?  If I were to hazard a guess, the solution says $$cl(B)=int(B)\ \cup \ \partial(B)= B \ \cup \{(0,0)\}$$ and that's it.  Is that right?

Comment: Please do not edit savagely your question.

Comment: First of all, set B has no interior point. Indeed for any point (1/n, 0) of B, there is no open ball with center this point included in B. Therefore $int(B)=\emptyset$. These points are in B therefore in its closure $\overline{B}$ (and also in the boundary $\partial(B)=\overline{B}\setminus int(B)=\overline{B}$). Here $\partial(B)=\overline{B}=B\cup\{(0,0)\}$

Answer (score 1):

If our set $B$ is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ s.t. $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then this is obviously a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but more specific, its a subset of the line $y=0$ in the real plane. So the closure of $B$ is ( i think obviously ) the set $\bar{B}=B\cup (0,0)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the parentheses are being used to denote an open interval.

Comment: I agree, but in the way it is written, it couldnt be a set of intervals because there is no such interval of this form. Maybe you recommend to talk about the set of intervals of the form $(0,1/n)$?

Comment: @Acccumulation It's unlikely unless you want to posit an explanation for how $B \subseteq (1,0]$ (or $B \subseteq [0,1)$).  Much more likely that the OP reinterpreted the answer key.

Comment: @Acccumulation I first thought like you, but it turned out that the author used $\{0\}$ to mean $\{(0,1)\}$. I usually write boldface $\bf{0}$ for the zero vector to avoid such confusion.